# Docker image changes inside kernel

Tags: docker

How the docker image is updated? is there any command that is executed to update docker image and How rw permission image is set when we mount an image?

Comment: Please do some basic research by yourself (try the Docker website) and then ask a specific question if there's something you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

See also (as [Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat) suggested) "[Updating and committing an image](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#updating-and-committing-an-image)"

> To update an image we first need to create a container from the image we’d like to update.

```
1/ run a container
docker run -t -i training/sinatra /bin/bash

2/ make some change 
root@0b2616b0e5a8:/# gem install json

3/ commit and get an updated image
docker commit -m "Added json gem" -a "Kate Smith" 0b2616b0e5a8 ouruser/sinatra:v2
```

That process is automated with a Dockerfile (run by a `docker build`): each line will create a container, make some changes and create a new image.

Those images are managed by the docker daemon.
See "[What is Docker’s architecture?](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#what-is-docker-s-architecture)"

[image: https://docs.docker.com/article-img/architecture.svg]